# CSS - Unable to center my image when using hover effect.

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

As per the title, I am unable to center my image when I input instructions for the image to tilt when mouse over. If I remove my 'tilt pic' div, I am able to center my image. Anyone can help point out my mistake please. Thank you.

```
<style>

img.downloadButton4{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.download_Button4{
width: 80%;
max-width: 1240px;
min-width: 760px;
min-height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.pic {
float: left;
height: 97px;
width: 242px;
margin: 0px;
overflow: hidden;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #111;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #111; 
}

.tilt {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}



.tilt:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

</style>


<body>
....<div class="download_Button4">
....<div class="tilt pic">
....<a href="#" target="_blank">
....<img class="downloadButton4" src="image.png"></a>
....</div>
....</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

let me rephrase the question, the image is always in the middle, the problem is that class "pic" has width of 242px  and float left make the div small down and go to the left

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    float: left;
}

.pic {
height: 97px;
width: 242px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #111;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #111; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLMTW/2/

you can either expand the .pic to 100% width or like me doint it, give it a container

hope this help